# truffle installed but not working

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-test, truffle-deployment

I'm using node version 12.20.2 and npm version 6.14.11 and installed truffle with cmd as administrator, the truffle framework version 5.5.12 has been installed but when I run any command in the vs code, it pops up with an error

```
PS E:\Testing (roughf work)> truffle version
truffle : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on 
this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at      
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ truffle version
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
PS E:\Testing (roughf work)> truffle init
truffle : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on 
this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at      
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ truffle init
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I don't know what to do with this, please help me asap

Comment: See if one of these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/q/41117421 work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Temporary solution.**

npx truffle version

npx truffle init

**For Permanent Solution :**

Any of the following solutions will remedy this issue:

1. Call the executable file explicitly using its .cmd extension (truffle.cmd compile)
2. Edit the system PATHEXT environment variable and remove .JS; from the list of executable extensions
3. Rename truffle.js to something else (truffle-config.js)
4. Use Windows PowerShell or Git BASH, as these shells do not have this conflict.

**Solution I suggest :**
Use CMD

[Source](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration/)